# Codeigniter - Update/Insert Data to Multiple Tables

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model

Table one : service, 
Table two : serviceImg

Service Table has a column as serviceImg. This serviceImg column of Service Table is equal to serviceImgId of serviceImg table. So I have done inner-join between these tables.

Summary: 
In short, I want to get data from two tables, insert into two tables, update two tables at a time.

How can I do this?

This is my model:

```
public function update_services($serviceId,$data)

    {

        $this->db->select('

        serviceImg.serviceImgId,
        serviceImg.serviceImgName,
        service.serviceId,
        service.serviceType,
        service.serviceCat,
        service.serviceNameEn,
        service.serviceNameAr,
        service.serviceDescEn,
        service.serviceDescAr,
        service.servicePrice,
        service.servicePack,
        service.serviceCreateUser,
        service.serviceCreateDate,
        service.serviceEditUser,
        service.serviceEditDate,
        service.serviceImg,
        service.serviceStatus,
        serviceCat.serviceCatId,
        serviceCat.serviceCatNameEn,
        serviceCat.serviceCatNameAr,
        serviceCat.serviceCatType,
        serviceCat.serviceCatCreateUser,
        serviceCat.serviceCatCreateDate,
        serviceCat.serviceCatEditUser,
        serviceCat.serviceCatEditDate,
        serviceCat.serviceCatActive
        ');



        $this->db->from('serviceImg');
        $this->db->set('serviceImg.serviceImgId = service.serviceImg');
        $this->db->join('service', 'serviceImg.serviceImgId = service.serviceImg', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('serviceCat', 'service.serviceCat = serviceCat.serviceCatId', 'LEFT');

        $this->db->where('serviceId', $serviceId);
        $this->db->where('service.serviceImg = serviceImg.serviceImgId');
        $this->db->update('service', $data);


    }
```

I am waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

you could use TRANSACTION of the codeigniter

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

here is the [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)

or you could use ajax to insert or update to multiple tables.